# Increase thickness of joined ListLogLogPlot[] curve

Tags: plotting, graphics, logarithmic-scale

Here is my code:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{{10^1, 10^1}, {10^3, 10^3}}, Joined -> True,  PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

The `PlotStyle->Thick` doesn't make it any thicker, nor does `Thickness[]`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PlotStyle->Thick` doesn't tell MMA what to do , try

```
ListLogLogPlot[{{10^1, 10^1}, {10^3, 10^3}}, Joined -> True,PlotStyle -> Thickness[.1]]
```

[image]